# How to find a toolstripitem based on its name being a variable and then change the checked value of it

Tags: vb.net, controls, contextmenu, toolstripmenu

I have a ContextMenuStrip called: `DGVContextStrip` its displayed when the user right clicks on my datagridview.

That MenuStrip contains an item called `AddUpgradeTagToolStripMenuItem`
which contains sub items(dropdownitems), these sub items are all named with a number in their name.
eg: `Add1ToolStripMenuItem`, `Add2ToolStripMenuItem`, `Add3ToolStripMenuItem`.... and so on until `Add25ToolStripMenuItem`.

When a user right clicks, on the Datagridview, I want to check if a cell contains the number "1" then if it does make `Add1ToolStripItem.checked = true`

I figured I would loop through the numbers 1 to 25, and in each loop check if the cell contains 1 and if true, change the checked value of the menu item. something like...

```
For i = 1 to 25
  If DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells("Text_Field").Value.ToString.Contains(i) then
  CType("Add" & i & "ToolStripMenuItem", ToolStripMenuItem).Checked = True

Next
```

but this doesn't work, iv seen examples online that use the control.find method but i couldn't get that to work for my use.
for example

```
Dim ControlName As String = "Add" & i & "ToolStripMenuItem"
CType(Me.Controls.Find(ControlName, True), ToolStripMenuItem).Checked = True
```

any ideas how I get this to work? I realise I could have used 25 if then else statements but I kind of wanted to keep the code far neater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ToolStripItem` is not a control to search for one in a `Control.ControlCollection`. You need to search a [`ToolStripItemCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripitemcollection?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) where it belongs.

Just like the `Control.ControlCollection.Find` method, the [`ToolStripItemCollection.Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripitemcollection.find?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) method can perform a deep search for an item.

Examples for your case:

```vb
Dim itemName As String = $"Add{i}ToolStripMenuItem"
Dim tsmi = yourContextMenuStrip.Items.
    Find(itemName, True).
    OfType(Of ToolStripMenuItem).
    FirstOrDefault()

If tsmi IsNot Nothing Then
    tsmi.Checked = True
End If
```

Alternatively, if you already know that the target item is one of the `AddUpgradeTagToolStripMenuItem` drop down items, then you can do:

```vb
Dim itemName As String = $"Add{i}ToolStripMenuItem"
Dim tsmi = DirectCast(AddUpgradeTagToolStripMenuItem, ToolStripMenuItem).
    DropDownItems.OfType(Of ToolStripMenuItem).
    FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name.Equals(itemName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))

If tsmi IsNot Nothing Then
    tsmi.Checked = True
End If
```

In case you need to check only one item from the collection:

```vb
Dim itemName As String = $"Add{i}ToolStripMenuItem"

For Each tsmi In DirectCast(AddUpgradeTagToolStripMenuItem, ToolStripMenuItem).
    DropDownItems.OfType(Of ToolStripMenuItem)

    If tsmi.Name.Equals(itemName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
        tsmi.Checked = True
    Else
        tsmi.Checked = False
    End If
Next
```

Comment: thank you , your first option worked for me. I actually couldn't get the second option to work, it simple would not compile mind you Visual Studio didn't recognise any error in the code so I'm not sure why it wouldn't compile.

Comment: @AndyAndromeda You're welcome. As for the second option's error, I don't know. It works for me.